# Show that for every $\epsilon > 0$ there exists an $M>0$ such that $|f(x)−f(y)|<\epsilon$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I'm kind of stuck on a question that I'm not sure how to approach.

Assume that $f(x) \rightarrow a$ for $x \rightarrow \infty$ and $f(x) \rightarrow b$ for $x \rightarrow -\infty$.
Show that for every $\epsilon>0$ there exists an $M>0$ such that  $|f(x)−f(y)|<\epsilon$ as long as $x,y>M$.

I'm not really sure how to approach this because I haven't seen the $|f(x)−f(y)|$ notation before and at the same time there's an "a" but also a "b" which makes it a bit different from what I've seen before. My thoughts so far is that I maybe could use one of the definitions from my book saying that: $f(x)\rightarrow a$ for $x \rightarrow \infty$ if for every $\epsilon>0$ there exists an $M>0$: $|| f(x)-a||<\epsilon$ for all $x>M$. But I'm also not sure about how to extract what I want from this. Any help is appreciated really!

Comment: Since you're only concerned with showing something for $x,y\gt M\gt0$, the hypothesis on $x\to-\infty$ is irrelevant. You need only assume that $f(x)$ has a limit as $x\to\infty$. (Ah, I see vadim123 made the same point in an answer.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: $$|f(x)-f(y)|=|f(x)-a+a-f(y)|\le |f(x)-a|+|f(y)-a|$$

The "b" is a red herring, as $x,y$ are both large and positive.

Comment: Uhh I could work with this. Thanks!

Comment: My pleasure, glad to help.

Comment: @Niktaneous Another note is that it should remind you a Cauchy sequence, you know that $x_n\rightarrow x$ iff $|x_n-x_m|<\varepsilon$  for $n,m>M$. The assertion in the question is a continuous version of this.

Comment: @Yanko Thank you for the note!

Comment: @vadim123 Hi, I hope that I can ask you one more question. I have to show that $f $ is uniformly continuous but I don't know how to do that with the given data. Do you have another helpful hint? :)

Comment: @Niktaneous, you should ask this as a separate question.

Comment: @vadim123 alright, thanks!

Comment: @Niktaneous: if in addition to the limits $a, b$ for $\pm\infty$ you are given that $f$ is continuous then it is uniformly continuous.